# websvn on bluehost

Tags: svn, websvn

I have been able to get SVN working on bluehost. Next I tried to set websvn and I am able to see the main websvn page but when I click on a repository then I get this error:

Error running this command: /home/username/system/bin/svn --non-interactive --config-dir /tmp log --xml --verbose --limit 2 'file:////home/username/devel//test/'

/home/username/system/bin/svn: line 60: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
/home/username/system/bin/svn: line 64: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory
ls: write error: Broken pipe
/home/username/system/bin/svn: line 88: /usr/bin/sed: No such file or directory

but /usr/bin/sed works fine from ssh. Any hints ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! :)

I found that svn is in fact a bash script! and it has hardcoded into it, in several places: /usr/bin/sed

so I just replaced them with: /home/username/bin/sed and it is working! :)

WebSvn is nicely working on bluehost now!!!

Answer (score 0):

The machine you log into with ssh might not be the one that is actually servicing HTTP request on the websvn URL you tried, and thus might actually not have /u/b/sed installed. You could try installing sed in your account and replace all references to /u/b/sed with the path to your own version. Does svn+ssh work fine for you?

Cheers,
   Volker

Answer (score 0):

Volker,

>
The machine you log into with ssh might not be the one that is actually servicing HTTP request on the websvn URL you tried, and thus might actually not have /u/b/sed installed.
>

Yes, that could be a reason. How could we check it ? With a php like this ? echo exec( "sed" );

>
You could try installing sed in your account and replace all references to /u/b/sed with the path to your own version.
>

Yes, I already tried this, changing the websvn settings, but somehow svn executes /usr/bin/sed and get the error again.

> Does svn+ssh work fine for you?

Yes, it works fine.

Thanks,